# How to detect end of line with Scanner from text file

Tags: java, arrays, file, input, line

So I'm reading an input text file that is 4 lines of single-space separated numbers. The text file is just:

```
5 
9 6
4 6 8
0 7 1 5
```

I'd like to input these numbers into a 2D array called rows. So for example, `rows[1][0]` should be `9`, the first number in the second row.

My problem is when I use the Scanner for `in.next()` or `in.nextInt()`, it ignores the end of the line and just keeps on going, so `rows[0][1]` ends up being `9` instead of `0`. I'd like for the array to finish populating with `0`'s if there is no number for that slot. So since the first row is only `1` number, `5`, I'd like for the array `rows[0][0]` to be `5`, but `rows[0][1]` to `rows[0][3]` to be `0`.

I've tried using a try/catch for `NoSuchElementException` and an if `in.hasNextLine()` but neither of those seemed to work.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please post your code? We'll be happy to help you

Answer (score 5):

You can use a Scanner to read individual tokens, and you can use a Scanner to read an entire line, but you cannot use a Scanner to do both.

What you want to do is first read the line into a String, then use a Scanner on that String to parse that line, e.g.:

```
BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(...);
String line;

while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line); 
    // use scanner here
}
```

You can also use a Scanner to read lines instead of a BufferedReader, but unless you have a specific requirement (e.g. you're trying to drop this into code that already uses a Scanner), it doesn't really matter how you read the lines.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use more than one Scanner. One Scanner gets each line with `nextLine()`, and then you feed the line obtained to the next Scanner analyzes each line's tokens. Just be sure to close() of the inner Scanner (and the outer one too) when done using it.

Pseudocode:

```
create fileScanner with file
while fileScanner has more lines
  get next line from fileScanner
  create new Scanner with next line, lineScanner
  while lineScanner has next, 
    get next token.
    do what you want with token.
  close of lineScanner
close fileScanner
```

Comment: @JasonC: oops!!! not sure what I was thinking. `close()` is the correct method to call. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a `BufferedReader` and `split`. The advantage of this is that you know how big to make your arrays in the second dimension as the `split` method will return an array and you can check its `length`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String s = "5\n"
            + "9 6\n"
            + "4 6 8\n"
            + "0 7 1 5";
    final InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
    final int[][] array = new int[4][];
    try (final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
        String line;
        for (int i = 0; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ++i) {
            final String[] tokens = line.split("\\s");
            final int[] parsed = new int[tokens.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < tokens.length; ++j) {
                parsed[j] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[j]);
            }
            array[i] = parsed;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
}
```

Output:

```
[[5], [9, 6], [4, 6, 8], [0, 7, 1, 5]]
```

As arrays don't expand it's not easy to use them in `while` loops that you don't know the size of. Using `split` allows you to simply do `final int[] parsed = new int[tokens.length];` which with a `Scanner` over whitespace you could not do.

The first dimension size is hard coded however as said your file always has 4 lines.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use an ArrayList or other container to remove the requirement of having to know the number of tokens ahead of time.

Comment: @JasonC of course, just that the OP specified that a 2d array was needed. I guess one could always to `List.toArray()` also, but that seems a little wasteful - copying data back and forth between `List`s and arrays.

Answer (score 1):

At the **end** of each line, there is **'\n'** ,and at the **first** of each line(**except first line**), there is **'\r'**. You can control your file by them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(
            "5\n9 6\n4 6 8\n0 7 1 5");

while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    String currentline = scanner.nextLine();

    String[] items = currentline.split(" ");
    int[] intitems = new int[items.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        intitem[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
    }
}
```